# addEmailInfo thrown an exception

Tags: email

i'm debugging a email function, the there is an exception terminate the program

```
<?
public function merchantEmailAction( )
    {
        $r = $this->getRequest();
        $id = $r->getParam('id');

        $deal    = Mage::getModel('deals/deal')->load($id, 'product_id');

        $merchant_id = $deal->merchant_id;
        $merchant = Mage::getModel('deals/merchant')->load($merchant_id);

        $name = $merchant->getMerchantName();
        $merchant_email = $merchant->getMerchant_email();


        if ( !name )
        {
            $to_name = "Merchant";
        }
        else
        {
            $to_name = $name;
        }

        $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('dailydeals_notification_merchant_email_template');

        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

        $sender = array("email" => Mage::getStoreConfig("deals/general/sender_emailid", $storeId), "name" => Mage::getStoreConfig( "deals/general/sender_name", $storeId));

        $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');

        $emailInfo->addTo((string)$merchant_email, (string)$to_name);

        $mail->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        die();



    }
?>
```

report generated

```
a:5:{i:0;s:1124:"Invalid method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::addEmailInfo(Array
(
    [0] => Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info Object
        (
            [_bccNames:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_bccEmails:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_toNames:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ABC
                        )

                )

            [_toEmails:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test@abc.com
                        )

                )

            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
            [_origData:protected] => 
            [_idFieldName:protected] => 
            [_isDeleted:protected] => 
            [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
)";i:1;s:1090:"#0 /home/test1/public_html/app/code/local/customext/Deals/controllers/Adminhtml/DealController.php(461): Varien_Object->__call('addEmailInfo', Array)
#1 /home/test1/public_html/app/code/local/customext/Deals/controllers/Adminhtml/DealController.php(461): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->addEmailInfo(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info))
#2 /home/test1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): customext_DailyDeals_Adminhtml_DealController->merchantEmailAction()
#3 /home/test1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('merchantEmail')
#4 /home/test1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /home/test1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /home/test1/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/test1/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:95:"/index.php/deals/adminhtml_deal/merchantEmail/id/172/key/5da1fd615e59adf472a55947b67ae5f0/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addEmailInfo` doesn't exist within the class you've instantiated (`Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template`).

It exists within `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer`

If you want to use that method, you'll need to instantiate the class as below:

```
Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer')
```

See below for this being used in-context (Mage/Admin/Model/User.php):

```
$mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
$emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
$emailInfo->addTo($this->getEmail(), $this->getName());
$mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
```

**However, I suspect this isn't the correct class for your usage anyway, which is where the other answers comes in.**

Answer (score 1):

The error message is straight forward. There is no method `addEmailInfo` in the class `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template`.
If you want to add recipients to the email do this:

After

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
```

add this

```
$mail->getMail()->addTo($merchant_email, '=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($to_name) . '?=')
```